# How to get text selection properties in Google Docs or Canvas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-docs, textselection

Is there a way to get the text selection properties from Google Docs? I am looking for something similar to `window.getSelection()` that works in Google docs or Canvas element.
I am developing a Chrome extension and I wanted to get text and position of text selection inside Google Docs.

This might be a duplicate question but wanted to check if anyone has figured it out.

Comment: See [the existing topics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-chrome-extension%5D+google+docs+canvas).

Comment: So there is no way to access selection without converting it to HTML?